# No entiendo como llevar a cabo este ejercicio

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Una pizzería, vende sus pizzas en tres tamaños:

pequeña (10 pulg. De diámetro); mediana (12 pulg. De diámetro); y grandes (16 pulg. De diámetro); Una pizza puede ser sencilla (con sólo salsa y carne), o con ingredientes extras, tales como pepinillos, champiñones o cebollas. Los propietarios desean desarrollar un programa que calcule el precio de venta de una pizza, dándole el tamaño y el número de ingredientes extras. El precio de venta será 1.5 veces el costo total, que viene determinado por el área de la pizza, más el número de ingredientes. En particular el costo total se calcula sumando:

- un costo fijo de preparación
- un costo base variable que es proporcional al tamaño de la pizza
- un costo adicional por cada ingrediente extra.

Por simplicidad se supone que cada ingrediente extra tiene el mismo costo por unidad de área. En C++

Comment: Necesito ayuda para resolver ese ejercico en c++ por favor, es para mañana

Comment: Aquí no se le hacen los deberes a nadie sino que se resuelven preguntas. Por favor pásate por el [tour] para entender cómo funciona [es.so] y por [ask] para ver cómo elaborar una pregunta adecuada. Esta pregunta, tal cual está no va a recibir respuestas

Comment: Pon un poco de tu código y te ayudamos a seguir :)

Comment: Solo llevo esto, bueno, no llevo nada realmente

Comment: y que sabes?? no eres capaz de hacer nada?? Algo tendras hecho @Estudiante

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Llevo 2 semanas intentando hacer el ejercicio y si he investigado un poco, ya se como definir una variable y estoy practicando para que me vaya mejor, decidí pedir ayuda porqué el ejercicio es mi parcial de programacion y no sabia como resolverlo.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Como ya te han dicho algunos usuarios por aquí e incluso yo misma, en StackOverflow no hacemos código, te ayudamos en los problemas que genere tu código.

Sin embargo he decidido escribirte esto porque es un programa muy sencillo y se te ve apurad@.

Por favor intenta entenderlo y lo que no entiendas pregunta sin problemas.

Este código no esta depurado, ni es completamente eficienciente, pero es un ejemplo fácil de como podría quedar.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//PRECIOS ESTABLECIDOS POR EL RESTUARANTE
float preparacion = 3;
float ingExtra = 1;

float pequenia = 2;
float mediana = 4;
float grande = 6;

//PROGRAMA
int main () {
  int sizePizza = 0;
  bool extra = 0;
  float precio = 0;
  int cantidad;

  cout << "Buenos dias" << endl << "¿De que tamaño desea su pizza?" << endl;
  cin >> sizePizza;

  while (sizePizza != 10 && sizePizza != 12 && sizePizza != 16){
    cout << "Error" << endl << "Su tamaño de pizza no es válido" << endl << "Vuelva a introducir un tamaño: " << endl;
    cin >> sizePizza;
  };

  switch(sizePizza){
    case 10:
      precio = precio + preparacion + pequenia;
      break;

    case 12:
      precio = precio + preparacion + mediana;
      break;

    case 16:
      precio = precio + preparacion+ grande;
      break;
  }

  cout << "¿La desea sencilla (solo con salsa y carne) [0] o con ingredientes extras? [1]" << endl;
  cin >> extra;

  if(extra == true){
    cout << "¿Cuantos ingredientes extra desea?" << endl;
    cin >> cantidad;

    precio = precio + cantidad*ingExtra;
    precio = precio * 1.5;

  }else{
    precio = precio * 1.5;
  }

  cout << "El coste de su pizza es de: " << precio << "€" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, no incentivemos esta clase de comportamientos.. si? Y menos con respuestas no explicadas.. ya que esta, es solo codigo...